# How allow less indent for closing parentheses inside a method with checkstyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Check style is telling me the closing parentheses has too low (8) of an indent level and that it should be 12. But I want it to be at the outer level as visually, it makes it much clearer that the checks are one "block" or collective result.

How do I do this (only for closing parentheses)?

```
private boolean someMethod()
{
    return (
        someCheck() &&
        anotherCheck() &&
        aThirdCheck()
    ); //This is the line it complains about
}
```

The error I get:

> 'method def' child has incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 12

Comment: Remove/disable this rule if it doesn't suit for you.

Comment: @davidxxx That would prevent it from forcing any indentation rules

Comment: Would it be an option to leave out the outer parentheses? They are redundant and seem to add nothing to the readability. If you're lucky, the problem goes away already.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not really standard.
Besides, the parentheses are not required for a series of `&&` with method invocations.
It may even make the reading harder.

Personally, I find it :

```
private boolean someMethod()
{
    return (
        someCheck() &&
        anotherCheck() &&
        aThirdCheck()
    ); //This is the line it complains about
}
```

less clear than that :

```
private boolean someMethod(){
    return someCheck() && anotherCheck() && aThirdCheck();
}
```

Comment: Well, in reality, the checks are much longer, so the line gets really long which is why we want it on multiple lines

Comment: Ok, I understand. But why do you want enclose all these boolean expressions between parentheses ? Maybe your example is too simple.

Comment: Perhaps there are some logical operations between the enclosed expressions in parentheses. But in the simple example it doesn't quite show anything like that.

Comment: It is quite simple. The actual method has 5 parameters, and we also do some checks on those for values, nulls, etc. So the line gets long

Answer (score 0):

> 'method def' child has incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 12
>   How do I do this (only for closing parentheses)?

There is no way to do this for IndentationCheck. It is very narrow how much you can customize this check, see http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Indentation . You can submit a change request to Checkstyle to support this case, but Indentation is one of the most complicated checks and not many people want to work on it.

You can suppress the violation using suppressions, or like someone else mentioned, you can remove/disable the check. I myself disable it because my group uses Eclipse and we enforce Eclipse to format the code on any save.